# knockout.js + back button - binding firing multiple times

Tags: jquery-mobile, knockout.js, cordova

I have the following setup: knockout, phonegap, JQM.

My application is based on http://propertycross.com/jquery-mobile/

until now my app was a 'tree' structure - i.e. the user click a menu entry and than when he wanted a different menu entry he had to click 'back' button to navigate back to the main menu.

but now I have a requirement that the user could jump to any menu entry from any where in the app.
but this mess up the 'back' functionality, since the view model is overridden by the new data...
i.e.

scenario A: I display the menu -> user click entry1 -> I applyBindings model1 to view1 -> view1 is displayed with a link to entry2 -> link is clicked -> I change the value in model1 -> view1 is displayed with new data -> user click back -> view1 is display but with the wrong data

I tried to solve it by applyBindings the new data, but this causes the data-bind handler to fire multiple times.
i.e.

scenario B: I display the menu -> user click entry1 -> I applyBindings model1 to view1 -> view1 is displayed with a link to entry2 -> link is clicked -> I applyBindings model2 to view1-> view1 is displayed with new data -> click handler are fire multiple time...

I could block the multiple execution with a flag - but I don't want to do it for EVERY function in my code...

I think there might be a solution using knockout template, but I couldn't find a proper example...

So my questions are:

1. Is knockout/phonegap/JQM not suited for this scenario: a cyclic app structure + back button ? or am I missing something?
2. Can it be solved with templates? how?
3. Any alternative solution?

Comment: Knockout is not a framework that handles routing - it is specifically made to handle two way data binding between the view and view model.  Your question on whether knockout is suited for your application is flawed because knockout doesn't handle routing generally...

Comment: thanks for your comment, I change my question to be more accurate.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is: generate views dynamically with jQuery append(), example:

> ```
> $.each(acts, function (key, act) {
>             if (!that.missionListViewModels[act.id]) {
>                 that.missionListViewModels[act.id] = new MissionListViewModel(application);
>                 $("body").append('<div data-theme="b" data-role="page" id="missionListView'+act.id+'"  data-url="missionListView'+act.id+'"  style="text-align:left;"><div data-bind="template: { name: \'missionListViewTemplate\', data: missionListModel }"></div></div>');
>             }
> }
> ```

NOTE:

1. I keep an array (that.missionListViewModels) with reference to the dynamically created missionListViewModels for future reference.
2. in order to keep the code in the append() short I use ko template, but this is not necessary.

The JQM/KO templates does not support the append() well:

1. the data-url, which was normally generated by the JQM was missing, therefore I had to add it manually.
2. data-i18n inside the template did not work, I had to use data-bind="text: ..." instead
3. <strike>'with' inside the template did not work, I had to change the code to avoid it.</strike>